How do I detect if a 3D line is intersecting a 3D triangle?
So I am making a 3D engine on scratch and I am making an collision engine. I would like it if the collision algorithm can show me the exact point in which the collision occured so i can take the player to the position of the collision.
I tried serching through the web and found lots upon lots of things talking about how to find points in 2D triangles and whenever I'd find a site about lines, it would either lead to lots of compicated stuff, not work, or it would be hard for me to understand. I would like to find a simple algorithm to replicate, or a complex one explained. I also want them to be fast.
